# difficulties with python assignment

Tags: python, file

I am new to programing and am having difficulties writing a program dealing with files. The program is to read a file, calculate an employees pay and an updated YTD  pay total. After calculations the program will write to a new file.

This is what I have so far:

```
empName = ""
prevYTD = 0.0
payRate = 0.0
hoursWorked = 0.0
recordCount = 0

def startUp():
    global empFile
    print "\n\n" + "PAYROLL REPORT".center(110)+"\n"
    print "Employee Name".ljust(30) + "Previous YTD".ljust(18) + \
          "Updated YTD".ljust(18) + "Pay Rate".ljust(13) + \
          "Hours Worked".ljust(19) + "Current Pay".ljust(8)
    print "-"* 109

    jobInfo = open("payroll_Assignment#7.txt", "r")

def readFile():
    global empName, prevYTD, payRate, hoursWorked, eof
    empRec = jobInfo.readline()
    if empRec == "":
        eof = True
    else:
        empName = empRec[:25]
        prevYTD = float(empRec[25:40])
        payRate = float(empRec[40:55])
        hoursWorked = float(empRec[55:])
        eof = False

def processRecords():
    global recordCount
    while not eof:
        recordCount +=1
        printRecord()
        readFile()


def printRecord():
    print empName, prevYTD, payRate, hoursWorked


def closeUp(): 
    jobInfo.close()
    print "\nNumber of records in the file was",recordCount

startUp()
readFile()
processRecords()
printRecord()
closeUp()
```

My problem is making a new file. The program is suppose to write to a new file and I don't know how to do it. Sorry for being so clumsy with this, I'm very new to it.

Comment: We know what the program is supposed to do, we know what you have done so far, but we **don't know** what your problem is...

Comment: If you don't ask a specific question, you won't get any answers.

Comment: Don't use global variables that way, don't use readFile name for function that only reads one line. Use parameters to functions!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is but some idiom can make it easy for you.

1. You can avoid testing for EOF and the while loop.

**File is iteratable hence you can iterate over it.**

```
for line in open('myfile','r'):
    doSomething(line)
```

See the details at : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

[Edit: Based on revised problem]

Opening a new file for writing should be easy in python

```
>>> logfile = open('test.log', 'w') # Opens a new file
>>> logfile = open('test.log', 'a') # Opens a existing file to append information
```

Look at the various modes of opening file in Python tutorial

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. The program is to read a file, calculate employee pay and update the YTD total. After the calculations the program is to write a new file. I can not figure out how to do the calculations, make, write, or save the updated file.

Comment: You can edit your question and add this text to it. Afterwards please delete this "answer" because obviously it is no answer to your question.

Comment: I have edited the question and my answer. You can delete your reply. Use comments, when you want to reply to others replies and posts.

Comment: Two Gregs? or Greg with two icons?

Comment: The program is to read a file, calculate an employees pay and an updated YTD  pay total. After calculations the program will write to a new file. I can not get the program to do the calculations or make, write, or save the updated file.